# TCPDF fill_color = array() does not accept variable?

Tags: tcpdf

`$myBgColor = '255, 255, 255';
 $this->Rect(0, 0, 210, 310, 'F', array(), array($myBgColor));`

Why does not it? Direct input works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this way:

`$myBgColor = $this->hex2rgb('#ffffff');`

see the function here:
[hex2rgb](http://bavotasan.com/2011/convert-hex-color-to-rgb-using-php/)

`$this->Rect(0, 0, 210, 310, 'F', array(), $myBgColor);`

works perfectly!